# python django one-to-one relations between two models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models and want to set a relation to them.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
  id   = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) # DB => PK, AI, NN
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  ...

class ModelB(models.Model):
  modelA = models.OneToOneField("ModelA", primary_key=True)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  ...
```

So I have a relationship between the two models. Is it possible to add a member to ModelA which stores the relation to ModelB without saving this relation to the database?

I would call it a dynamically created relation or something. Any hints oder suggestions how to let both models know each other?

I think it would be benefiting if the relation on one model can be done dynamically. Otherwise I'll get some trouble storing the models because one of the IDs won't be stored if I save one of the models.

I want to have the relation on both models so I can easily use the models as inline in django-admin.

regards

Answer (score 0):

The reverse relation in Django is created by default.

To get the ModelA you will use:

```
ModelA.objects.filter(modelb__pk = 1)
```

You will find more details here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I can't get how this can help me showing ModelA as an inline of ModelB in django-admin. I know that there ist no reverse inlining and I want to wokr around by having a relation member at ModelA

Answer (score 0):

Django ORM will save ModelA first, then ModelB, in order to maintain data integrity in the DB.

Django can try saving multiple items in one transaction, and this way, if you cancel it, nothing will be saved, **but** this is possible in shell or in Python code. Over HTTP you can't maintain a transaction over several queries so far.

If you need to show model A as inline of model B, you need a custom admin interface, not new fields/models. I can't tell how to write custom admin widgets. I did do a similar thing with custom editor views & templates & Javascript. I stored the unsaved models in `request.session`.